# Location of fonts downloaded within MS Word / Powerpoint / etc

Tags: ms-office, font

In Microsoft Office 365 on the Mac, I have downloaded (i.e., clicked the icon that looks like a cloud with a down arrow) some fonts that are listed in the font dropdown menu. (*More specifically, I've downloaded them using PowerPoint and Word, both of which are version 16.82 on my machine.*)

I want to locate them, but they are **[1]** not in any of the 3 Mac system font folders (`~/Library/Fonts`, `/Library/Fonts`, `/System/Library/Fonts`) and **[2]** not in any of the application packages (e.g., `/Applications/Microsoft Word.app/Contents/Resources/DFonts`).

Does anyone know where these fonts go?

Comment: Can you name the fonts?

Comment: Sure, right now I'm looking for Aptos Display and Aptos Serif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1433509/location-of-cloud-fonts-from-ms-office) suggests that MS's 'Cloud fonts' are stored in

```
~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/FontCache/4/CloudFonts
```

... and indeed I have a font in that location.

Comment: I have Aptos Display (and 5 others) in that location.